# Plot Histogram on different axes

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am reading CSV file:

```
 Notation Level   RFResult   PRIResult   PDResult  Total Result
 AAA       1       1.23        0           2         3.23
 AAA       1       3.4         1           0         4.4
 BBB       2       0.26        1           1.42      2.68
 BBB       2       0.73        1           1.3       3.03
 CCC       3       0.30        0           2.73      3.03
 DDD       4       0.25        1           1.50      2.75
 AAA       5       0.25        1           1.50      2.75
 FFF       6       0.26        1           1.42      2.68
 ...
 ...
```

Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.rad_csv('home\NewFiles\Files.csv')
Notation = df['Notation']
Level = df['Level']
RFResult = df['RFResult']
PRIResult = df['PRIResult']
PDResult = df['PDResult']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=7, ncols=1)
ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6, ax7 = axes.flatten()
n_bins = 13
ax1.hist(data['Total'], n_bins, histtype='bar') #Current this shows all Total Results in one plot 
plt.show()
```

**I want to show each Level Total Result in each different axes like as follow:**

ax1 will show Level 1 Total Result

ax2 will show  Level 2 Total Result

ax3 will show  Level 3 Total Result

ax4 will show  Level 4 Total Result

ax5 will show  Level 5 Total Result

ax6 will show  Level 6 Total Result

ax7 will show  Level 7 Total Result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select a filtered part of a dataframe just by indexing: `df[df['Level'] == level]['Total']`.  You can loop through the axes using `for ax in axes.flatten()`. To also get the index, use `for ind, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten())`. Note that Python normally starts counting from 1, so adding 1 to the index would be a good choice to indicate the level.

Note that when you have backslashes in a string, you can escape them using an r-string: `r'home\NewFiles\Files.csv'`.

The default ylim is from 0 to the maximum bar height, plus some padding. This can be changed for each `ax` separately. In the example below a list of ymax values is used to show the principle.

`ax.grid(True, axis='both)` sets the grid on for that `ax`. Instead of 'both', also 'x' or 'y' can be used to only set the grid for that axis. A grid line is drawn for each tick value. (The example below tries to use little space, so only a few gridlines are visible.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame({'Level': np.random.randint(1, 6, N), 'Total': np.random.uniform(1, 5, N)})

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=1, sharex=True)
ymax_per_level = [27, 29, 28, 26, 27]
for ind, (ax, lev_ymax) in enumerate(zip(axes.flatten(), ymax_per_level)):
    level = ind + 1
    n_bins = 13
    ax.hist(df[df['Level'] == level]['Total'], bins=n_bins, histtype='bar')
    ax.set_ylabel(f'TL={level}') # to add the level in the ylabel
    ax.set_ylim(0, lev_ymax)
    ax.grid(True, axis='both')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: A stacked histogram with custom legend and custom vertical lines could be created as:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame({'Level': np.random.randint(1, 6, N),
                   'RFResult': np.random.uniform(1, 5, N),
                   'PRIResult': np.random.uniform(1, 5, N),
                   'PDResult': np.random.uniform(1, 5, N)})
df['Total'] = df['RFResult'] + df['PRIResult'] + df['PDResult']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=1, sharex=True)
colors = ['crimson', 'limegreen', 'dodgerblue']
column_names = ['RFResult', 'PRIResult', 'PDResult']
level_vertical_line = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for level, (ax, vertical_line) in enumerate(zip(axes.flatten(), level_vertical_line), start=1):
    n_bins = 13
    level_data = df[df['Level'] == level][column_names].to_numpy()
    # vertical_line = level_data.mean()
    ax.hist(level_data, bins=n_bins,
            histtype='bar', stacked=True, color=colors)
    ax.axvline(vertical_line, color='gold', ls=':', lw=2)
    ax.set_ylabel(f'TL={level}')  # to add the level in the ylabel
    ax.margins(x=0.01)
    ax.grid(True, axis='both')
legend_handles = [Patch(color=color) for color in colors]
axes[0].legend(legend_handles, column_names, ncol=len(column_names), loc='lower center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.02))
plt.show()
```

[image: stacked histogram]

Comment: How should i label the level number for yaxis? I tried plt.ylabel inside the loop but it shows only last level in y axis. it doesnt show all the level number for y axis.

Comment: I got that. there is anyway i can able to add string with level number. like ax.set_ylabel('TL' + level)?

Comment: You need either `ax.set_ylabel('TL' + str(level))` or `ax.set_ylabel(f'TL{level}')`. See [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) for more info about f-strings.

Comment: There is anyhow i can add one big title at the top? Like 'Regs vs level'. i know plt.title('Regs vs level') but what i do this it does not put the title at the top.

Comment: `plt.suptitle('Regs vs level')`

Comment: how should i change each axis y limit? i want to create a custom y limit for each axis?

Comment: Matplotlib automatically sets the ylim's min to 0 and the max to the highest bar plus some padding. Do you want something else?  If you want all ylims the same, you can add `sharey=True` to `plt.subplots(..., sharey=True)`

Comment: I want to set a different y limit for each Level.

Comment: You can call `ax.set_ylim(0, ymax)` to the desired value for each ax. Or maybe `values, bins, patches = ax.hist(...)` and then `ax.set_ylim(0, values.max()*1.1)`.

Comment: ax.set_ylimit(0, ymax) set up a same ylimit for all axes but i do not know how set up a custom ylimit for each level. Also, how should enable grid. i tried plt.grid(True). but it can not show the grid on each axes

Comment: Thanks for stacked bar. I have one question is that how should i show ['Total'] mean value as vertical line respect to each TL level in histogram plot?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: I want to set custom vertical line for each TL. for example TL1 = 1, TL2=2, TL3=3, TL4=4, TL5=5,How should i do that? I tried ax.axvline(x=1, color='r', linestyle='--', linewidth=2) but this line shows x=1 vertical line on every TL. I dont want to do that. I want to show custom.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: I leaved the Mean Vertical line in the plots. How should i show mean text next to mean line on each TL? Basically i want to show mean value next to mean line on each TL.

Comment: How should i show only level 6 RF_result, PDR_result, and PRI_result in pie chart?